# Cuda Toolkit for jetson

Tags: python, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson

I was installing cuda toolkit for jetson , and for network reason the installation failed and so I have Unmet dependencies, but when using `apt --fix-broken install` it gives the same error what to do , I can not install any thing because of this error .
when installing anything it gaves dependencies error

Comment: try to `pip uninstall` ....  then try to install again.